# Решить задание с помощью циклов в c++

Tags: c++, циклы

дано число A(>1) Вывести наименьшее из целых чисел K, для которых сумма 1+1/2...+1/K будет больше A, и саму эту сумму.(код не работает)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    double sumx,minx;
    int k,a;
    cout << "Введите a: ";
    cin >> a;
    sumx = 0.0;
    minx = 0.0;
    k = 1;
    if (a > 1) {
        while (sumx <=- a) {
            minx = k;
            sumx += (1 / minx);
            k++;
        }
        cout << sumx << minx;
    }
    else
    cout << "Неверное значение";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ещё добавьте исходник Вашего решения как код, а не как картинка

Comment: Код. Буковками. Пожалуйста. С картинок неудобно читать, нельзя копировать, чтоб воспроизвести в IDE.

Comment: И в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: @АОоаоаа, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив код туда, используя встроенное форматирование

Comment: Точно `while (sumx <=- a) {`? Именно меньше "минус а"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас сумма не считается. Потому что деление целого на целое в результате даст целое, в вашем случае всегда `0`.

```
double sumx;
int k;
sumx += (1 / k);
```

Нужно чтобы результат деления был `double`:

```
// так
double sumx, k;
sumx += (1 / k);

// или так
double sumx;
int k;
sumx += (1.0 / k);
```

И почему данное в условии число `A` у вас целое? Просто сумма `1+1/2...+1/K` всегда меньше `2`. И тогда число из условия должно быть в диапазоне `1 < A < 2`, т.е. оно должно быть вещественным `double`. Иначе цикл `while (sumx <= a)` будет вечным.

Comment: спасибо большое, все получилось!

Comment: Не к вопросу и не к решению... но интересно замерять, сколько времени будет считать, например, до 100, не говорю уж о чем-то большем... :) И, кстати, в *тексте* вопроса уже деление у автора верное. Вот так и делают из отвечающих глупцов, которые вроде как указывают на несуществующие ошибки...